# Query on creating new Events in Salesforce

Tags: events, salesforce, task

When creating a new event in salesforce, linked to an opportunity, there is an option to 'add invitees' where you can select multiple contacts. When adding invitees, does this send a notification to these contacts with the info entered within this event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**.

Salesforce will send an email to notify invitees about the meeting.

If your need to add custom fields, you should change the email template.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I did a couple of tests to check this by adding some test contacts to the invitees, I did not receive any notifications as such. Weird..